# I Managing UI references across ng2 components in nativescript

Tags: angular, nativescript

I am building a nativescript mobile app, with Angular 2. I have a "page" component, which includes a "section" component which includes a "button" component. I used to just have one component but am breaking it all down however, the button has a click Handler which triggers an animation, the function called goes like this:

```
export function socialAnimate(page, clicked) {
    var google = page.getViewById("google");
}
```

where the button component calls it like:

```
@Component({
    selector: "button",
    template: `<Button row="8" col="2" icon="res://key" class="login" rippleColor="#f1f1f1" (tap)="socialClick()"></Button>`,
    styleUrls: ["Components/Button/login.css"],
    directives: []
})
export class Button implements OnInit {

    page: Page;

    loginClicked: boolean = false;

    ngOnInit() {
        this.page = <Page>topmost().currentPage;
    }
    socialClick() {
        this.loginClicked = socialAnimate(this.page, this.loginClicked);
    }
}
```

However, having refactored the code to produce these child components, I am getting an error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined

I have been through with a debugger, page is defined, but none of the `getiewById`'s are working, I presume I am getting the ​*wrong*​ page? but why is the topmost() not working, or is something else likely wrong?

## Update:

I have also tried this approach:

```
export class PageCmp {
    page: Page;
    ngOnInit() {
        this.page = <Page>topmost().currentPage;
        this.page.actionBarHidden = true;
    }
    @ViewChild(Button) child: Button;

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        this.child.setPage(this.page);
    }
}
```

and then in my button component I added the function:

```
setPage(page: Page) {
    this.page = page;
}
```

## EDIT:

So I now have this Button Component:

```
import {Component, ViewChild, ElementRef} from "@angular/core";

@Component({
    selector: "button",
    template: `<FAB row="8" col="2" icon="res://google" class="fab-button" id="google" rippleColor="#f1f1f1" (tap)="login('Google')"></FAB>`,
    directives: []
})
export class Button {

    @ViewChild('google') google: ElementRef;

    socialClick() {

        if (this.loginClicked == false) {
            this.google.nativeElement.style.opacity = 1;
        }

        this.loginClicked = !this.loginClicked;

    }
}
```

However, `@ViewChild('google') google: ElementRef;` and as such I am getting an error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of undefined

Comment: What happens with the updated approach? Does have `this.child` some value in `ngAfterViewInit()`. Can you `console.log(this.child)` there or debug by other means?

Comment: If you want to query the `<FAB` element this way it needs to have a template variable like `<FAB #google row="8" ...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use View child you need to first import ElmentRef from core

```
import {ElementRef} from "@angular/core";
```

All of your @ViewChild need to be of the type ElmentRef, then to access the actual elment you need to use nativeElement

```
@ViewChild('login') child: ElementRef;

ngAfterViewInit() {
    let view = this.child.nativeElement;
}
```

hope that helps

Comment: Why would that be? `ElementRef` is returned when the element is not an Angular component. If the `@ViewChild(Login)` returns something, then only if it found a component of that type and than also returns that type. If you use a template variable `<div #someElement>` and query it using `@ViewChild('someElement')` then you get an `ElementRef`.

Comment: that was a typo on my part, from when i copied an pasted his, I think your right, I wasn't sure what he was trying to get  if it was a custom angular component or native elment.

Comment: I guess I see now what you mean. You actually **want** the `ElementRef`. In this case I think you can also use `@ViewChild(Login, {read: ElementRef}) child:ElementRef;` (not tested myself yet for this exact use case).

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer and Josh, please see my EDIT on the question, I have followed this answer, but am now getting an undefined error...